# If $f$ has derivative in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, then it is absolutely continuous in any bounded interval

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, absolute-continuity

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, with derivative in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. That is, there exists $h\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ such that:
$$
\lim_{y\to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} 
\left| \frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}- h(x)\right|^p\; dx =0
$$
Prove that $f$ is absolutely continuous in any bounded interval.

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that our bounded interval is $I$ and $(x_k,y_k)$ is a finite sequence of pairwise disjoint sub-intervals of $I$, fulfilling $\sum_k|y_k-x_k|=\delta$. We have
$$ f(y_k)-f(x_k) = \int_{x_k}^{y_k}h(x)\,dx $$
hence by the triangle inequality and Holder's inequality
$$ \sum_k\left|f(y_k)-f(x_k)\right|\leq \int_{\bigcup_k(x_k,y_k)}|h(x)|\,dx\leq \|h\|_p\,\delta^{1-\frac{1}{p}} $$
and as long as $\delta\to 0$ we have that the LHS tends to zero as well.
 This proves the absolute continuity of $f$.

Comment: Great, the only assumption is not clear enough is why $f(y_k)-f(x_k)= \int_{x_k}^{y_k}h(x)\; dx$, I can see this is a generalization of FTC.  As the integral is $0$ in limit and the integrand is positive then it must be $0$ almost everywhere.  And so $\frac{f(x-y)-f(x)}{y}= h(x)$ almost everywhere. From that I can manage to prove the representation used?

Comment: @michaelaba: exactly, if $f$ is a differentiable function we have $h(x)=f'(x)$; here $h$ is simply a weak derivative of $f$, which under the integral sign behaves just like the usual derivative.

Comment: Thanks ! Great and useful!

Comment: Jack, can you write out of proof of the relation $f(y)-f(x)=\int_x ^{y}h(x)dx$ starting with the definition of derivative in $L^{p}$. To me that looks hard.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: consider a smooth and concentrated kernel $K_\varepsilon(x)\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and replace $f$ with $g=f*K_\varepsilon$, which is a $C^1$ function. Then $g(y_k)-g(x_k) = \int_{x_k}^{y_k}(f*K_{\varepsilon})'(x)\,dx $, and as $\varepsilon\to 0$ the LHS converges to $f(y_k)-f(x_k)$ while the RHS converges to $\int_{x_k}^{y_k}h(x)\,dx$.

Comment: In layman's terms: what is the point of defining *weak derivatives* if they do not behave like standard derivatives when integrated?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio : I do not really understand all the details of your proof. For the RHS, a simple argument with the Dominated Convergence Theorem suffices. On the other hand, we can only guarantee the pointwise convergence of $f$ if $f$ is at $L^\infty$ continuous at an open set containing those points. (otherwise, all we have is $L^p$ convergence)